# Polynomial fullfilling certain derivative properties

Tags: polynomials

I have to solve the following task:

For an n $\in \mathbb N$, find a polynomial f(x), s.t. $f^{(k)}(1) = 0$ for $\forall$ k < n and $f^{(n)}(1)=1$.

I have tried out a couple of variations - without success. Is there a *systematic* way to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: The general systematic way is the Taylor expansion about $1$. In this case we get $\frac{1}{n!}(x-1)^n$ as the polynomial of smallest degree.

Comment: But how do I know that?

Comment: If you are familiar with Taylor expansion, you have seen it many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to look for a polynomial centered at $0$ first, then shift the domain.

If $p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k x^k$, then $p^{(j)}(0) = j!p_j$.

Usin the numbers you provided, this gives $p(x) = \frac{1}{n!} x^n$.

Now shift the domain, to get $f(x) = p(x-1) = \frac{1}{n!} (x-1)^n$.

Comment: wow, really nice, thanks